# Why is this happening? VBA questions

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having a problem (I have no idea if it is a problem or not, but it's kind of annoing becaause never happened before) with openning the VBA. The thing is, whenever I press Alt + f11 I enter in a module called RibbonX_code and it has the followed code:

```
Option Explicit
Const sResourcePrefix As String = "RES_"

'Get Culture
Private Function GetATPUICultureTag() As String
    Dim shTemp As Worksheet
    Dim sCulture As String
    Dim sSheetName As String

    sCulture = Application.International(xlUICultureTag)
    sSheetName = sResourcePrefix + sCulture

    On Error Resume Next
    Set shTemp = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sSheetName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If shTemp Is Nothing Then sCulture = GetFallbackTag(sCulture)

    GetATPUICultureTag = sCulture
End Function

'Entry point for RibbonX button click
Sub ShowATPDialog(control As IRibbonControl)
    Application.Run ("fDialog")
End Sub

'Callback for RibbonX button label
Sub GetATPLabel(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef label)
    label = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sResourcePrefix + GetATPUICultureTag()).Range("RibbonCommand").Value
End Sub

'Callback for screentip
Public Sub GetATPScreenTip(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef label)
    label = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sResourcePrefix + GetATPUICultureTag()).Range("ScreenTip").Value
End Sub

'Callback for Super Tip
Public Sub GetATPSuperTip(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef label)
    label = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sResourcePrefix + GetATPUICultureTag()).Range("SuperTip").Value
End Sub

Public Sub GetGroupName(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef label)
    label = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sResourcePrefix + GetATPUICultureTag()).Range("GroupName").Value
End Sub

'Check for Fallback Languages
Private Function GetFallbackTag(szCulture As String) As String
    'Sorted alphabetically by returned culture tag, then input culture tag
    Select Case (szCulture)
        Case "rm-CH"
            GetFallbackTag = "de-DE"
        Case "ca-ES", "ca-ES-valencia", "eu-ES", "gl-ES"
            GetFallbackTag = "es-ES"
        Case "lb-LU"
            GetFallbackTag = "fr-FR"
        Case "nn-NO"
            GetFallbackTag = "nb-NO"
        Case "be-BY", "ky-KG", "tg-Cyrl-TJ", "tt-RU", "uz-Latn-UZ"
            GetFallbackTag = "ru-RU"
        Case Else
            GetFallbackTag = "en-US"
    End Select
End Function
```

I have no idea what it is, it started happen today and it never happened before. I'm new in vba and I just want to know what it is, so if it is normal, just close the topic.

Comment: It's from the Analysis tool-pak add-in. If you don't want to see it, *File* > *Options* > *Add-ins* > *Manage Excel Add-Ins* > *Go* > and uncheck Analysis ToolPak.

Comment: @BigBen Thank you man it worked. One question, is that important for vba to run correctly or I simply uncheck if I want?

Comment: Just uncheck it... You don't need it for other macros to work

Answer (score 0):

I could have sworn this has been asked and answered here already, but in any case...

This is due to the Analysis ToolPak add-in being loaded. To hide it, navigate to *File* > *Options* > *Add-Ins* > *Manage Excel Add-Ins* > *Go* and uncheck Analysis ToolPak.